# Some Error in a simple java code

Tags: java, io

this is a simple Java code which reverses a String without using any String API function, but in the last line, when it prints the reversed string, there is some problem in output statement (System.out.println())

Here's the code :

```
class StringReverse
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        int str[] = new int[100];
        int i=0,j;
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        while(true)
        {
            str[i]=System.in.read();
            if(str[i++]==13)
                break;
        }
        String reversed="",simple = new String(str,0,i-1);
        System.out.println(simple);

        // now reversing the string
        for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
            reversed+=((char)str[j]);
        System.out.println("String is "+reversed);
    }
}
```

Sample output is
[image]

Comment: What happened when you stepped through this with a debugger, or at least a piece of paper and a pencil?

Comment: @kevin : if you just print 
System.out.println(reversed) , it is OK
but if you print some string before this, it shows an unexpected output, i.e. 'reversed' is printed before that string literal

Comment: @sotirios : first one reads the string character by character into integer array and second one stops on carriage return (Enter)

Comment: @Gagan93 those were not questions, they were clues =)

Comment: @sotirios : it stops at that point, and is not causing any problem, morover typcasting is causing this to happen .
the problem is in last line

Comment: @Gagan93 : it actually is the problem, but it is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are running on Windows. When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, two special characters get transmitted - `<CR>`, or `\r`, and `<LF>`, or `\n`  <sup>*</sup>. You are trapping the `\n`, and stop reading. However, `\r` remains in the buffer, and becomes the first character of the reversed string. That's why the reversed string gets printed on top of your `"String is "` output.

Here is what's going on at the end, step-by-step:

- `"String is "` gets printed; the cursor is at the position number ten (zero-based)
- The first character of the reversed string `"gagan\r"` gets printed. The character is invisible, but the position of the cursor becomes zero; the cursor remains on the same line
- The reversed string `"nagag"` gets printed over the `"Strin"` portion of the `"String is "`
- Now you see the output `"nagagg is"`

<sup>*</sup> `<CR>` stands for "carriage return"; `<LF>` stands for "line feed".

Comment: is there any method to flush that character before doing anything else ?

Comment: @Gagan93 If you replace `str[i++]==13` with `str[i++]=='\r'`, you would trap that character yourself. This, however, would make your code incompatible with UNIX-based systems, so I would use `if (str[i]=='\r' || str[i]=='\n') ...` and have `i++` on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, Instead of having unneeded lines of code, you could simply do that by the use of StringBuilder. For more information about the StringBuilder visit this: [Class StringBuilder - Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Below is an implementation with the use of StringBuilder.

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseString{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //String s = getString("Please enter a string");
        //you can either pass the getString directly into the constructor of 
        //StringBuilder or first instanciated and pass that String.
        StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder(getString("Please enter a String"));
        //A build-in method of the StringBuilder class that reverses a StringBuilder.
        StringBuilder k = rev.reverse();
        //A cmd print
        print("The reverse is: "+k);
    }

    public static String getString(String msg) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        print(msg);
        String s = in.nextLine();
        return s;
    }

    public static void print(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```